# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruptures.datasets'

Tags: python

Probably I am opening the 1.000.000 question to a modul not found error. But I installed `ruptures` with `pip install ruptures`, but somehow when I run my script I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 12
     10 from noisy_timeseries_c import *
     11 from outlier_detection_c import *
---> 12 from changepoint_detection_c import *
     13 from modelfactory_c import *
     14 #from visualize import *
     15 
     16 # Loading default config and updating with custom values from request body

File ~/workspace/Azure/changepoint_detection_c.py:3
      1 #changepoint detection
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import ruptures as rpt
      6 def changepoint(df, minimumsize):
      7     df = df.reset_index()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ruptures/__init__.py:3
      1 """Offline change point detection for Python."""
----> 3 from .datasets import pw_constant, pw_linear, pw_normal, pw_wavy
      4 from .detection import Binseg, BottomUp, Dynp, KernelCPD, Pelt, Window
      5 from .exceptions import NotEnoughPoints

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruptures.datasets'
```

I tried to uninstall and install the package again, but it still not work.

The modul version is ruptures Version: 1.1.8

Comment: What is the content of `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ruptures/` ? What version of the module do you ahve installed?

Comment: Name: ruptures
Version: 1.1.8
Summary: Change point detection for signals in Python.
Home-page: https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/
Author: Charles Truong, Laurent Oudre, Nicolas Vayatis
Author-email: charles@doffy.net
License: BSD-2-Clause
Location: /config/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: numpy, scipy
Required-by: 
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: Please post additional info by using the [edit] button. That was only half of what I asked

Comment: maybe you are executing with a virtual machine that doesn't have the installs.